# SetInterval runs only one time

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm trying to display the time on a clock that I created on my website, so I used the setInterval to display the time every seconds. 
But it only runs once and I don't know what to do. 
However, Firefox doesn't notice any error in my code.

```
var date = new Date(); //Time of the clock in-game
var hours;
var minutes;
var seconds;

var display_hours; // Displayers for the time
var display_minutes;
var display_seconds;

window.onload = function() {
    display_hours = document.getElementById("hour");
    display_minutes = document.getElementById("minute");
    display_seconds = document.getElementById("second");
};

function time_on() {
    hours = date.getHours();
    if (hours < 10) {
        hours = "0" + hours;
    };
    minutes = date.getMinutes();
    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    };
    seconds = date.getSeconds();
    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    };

    display_hours.textContent = hours;
    display_minutes.textContent = minutes;
    display_seconds.textContent = seconds;
};

var go_time = setInterval(time_on, 1000); // Display time on the clock every seconds
```

I want to be able to clear this interval later in the code.

Comment: Why are you defining `go_time` twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that `window.onload` triggers *after* you already created the interval, so inside the interval handler, `display_{hours,minutes,seconds}` are undefined and cause your code to crash.

Try starting the interval from within the `onload` handler:

```
window.onload = function() {
    display_hours = document.getElementById("hour");
    display_minutes = document.getElementById("minute");
    display_seconds = document.getElementById("second");
    var go_time = setInterval(time_on, 1000);
};
```

**EDIT**: also, make sure you actually update `date` each time:

```
function time_on() {
  date = new Date();
  ...
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work neither : the time is diplayed one time and that's all

Comment: See edit: you don't update `date` ;D

Comment: It's working, thanks a lot. When I think about it, it makes sense

Comment: Another option, is just place your script just before body close tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple clock:

```
function startTime() {
var today = new Date();
var h = today.getHours();
var m = today.getMinutes();
var s = today.getSeconds();
m = checkTime(m);
s = checkTime(s);
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
return i;
}
```

and in the body put this:

```
<body onload="startTime()">
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to clear the interval later so I have to put it in a var, is it right ?

Comment: "try this" is not an answer. What have you changed and why?